# Run android emulator on remote machine

Tags: appium

I am running appium test and during the test I am trying to activate emulator from remote machine...
My test code is starting appium server on the remote machine and then creates android driver.
In the remote machine I have emulator and appium installed without running the server.
The remote machine IP is : `192.168.14.23 port 4723`
In the running machine I have also appium installed.
I am using appium version 1.4.13

Here is the log:

> Going to execute start appium server: cmd /c
>   C://appium//Appium//node.exe
>   C://appium//Appium//node_modules\appium\bin\appium.js --address
>   192.168.14.23 --port 4723
>       [33mwarn[39m: Appium support for versions of node < 0.12 has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Please
>   upgrade!
>       [31merror[39m: Couldn't start Appium REST http interface listener. Requested address is not available.
>       2015-11-19 14:26:03,586  INFO [main] (Drivers.java:329) - Trying to set ANDROID driver
>       org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote
>   server or browser start-up failure.
>       Build info: version: '2.42.2', revision: '6a6995d31c7c56c340d6f45a76976d43506cd6cc', time: '2014-06-03
>   10:52:47'
>       System info: host: 'QTVR-AII015', ip: '192.168.23.43', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version:
>   '1.7.0_79'
>       Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:593)
>         at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:180)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:240)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:126)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:153)
>         at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:109)
>         at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.(AndroidDriver.java:39)
>         at com.ui.service.drivers.Drivers$Appium.createAndroidDriver(Drivers.java:362)
>         at com.ui.service.drivers.Drivers$Appium.setDriver(Drivers.java:338)
>         at com.ui.service.drivers.Drivers.setDriver(Drivers.java:52)
>         at appium.messaging.basic_concurrent.VisitorThread.initAppiumDriver(VisitorThread.java:67)
>         at appium.messaging.basic_concurrent.VisitorThread.init(VisitorThread.java:57)
>         at appium.messaging.basic_concurrent.VisitorThread.

Comment: And what is your question ? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have you tried pinging your remote machine from execution machine. Try `ping 192.168.14.23` in a commad prompt to check weather you can access the remote machine from yours

Comment: Yes, I can ping but still fails

Answer (score 0):

**Disable the firewall of both the machines and retry..**

You can execute test while hosting appium server in remote machine..

This may also occur if you use virtual network..
is your remote machine is VM??